# Retrieve href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML page contains:

```
<a id="show" href="monlien1" onclick="show()"> Facebook</a>
<a id="show" href="monlien2" onclick="show()"> Twitter</a>
<a id="show" href="monlien3" onclick="show()"> Google</a>
```

I want to show the `href` attribute for each click. For example if I click on "Facebook", it will show `monlien1`, on "Twitter" `monlien2`, etc.

I tried this but it shows only the value of the first link, `monlien1`, even if I click on "Twitter" or "Google".

```
function show(){
    var lien=$('#show').attr('href');
    alert(''+lien+'');
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with same ID. `$('#show')` will always select the *first* elements with that ID.

Comment: ID's has to be unique

Comment: do one thing put your href value inside value tag and use as           <a href="#" value="monlien1" id = "show" onclick="this.value()">Facebook</a>

Comment: FYI, `alert(''+lien+'');` is the same as `alert(lien);`. Adding empty strings at the beginning and end serve no purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Start using classes (you shouldn't have the same ID multiple times, it will cause issues) also, pass in `this` as an argument:

```
<a class="show" href="monlien1" onclick="show(this)"> Facebook</a>
<a class="show" href="monlien2" onclick="show(this)"> Twitter</a>
<a class="show" href="monlien3" onclick="show(this)"> Google</a>

function show(obj) {
   var lien = obj.href;
   alert(''+lien+'');
}
```

Edit: Thanks @FelixKling -- the equivalent to `$('#show').attr('href')` is `obj.getAttribute('href')`. `obj.href` will return a full URL not the actual value of the href attribute.

Comment: +1 for using pure js.  it's a great learning tool if you help people understand what jQuery is built on.  Also - check your quotes. `alert(''+lien+'')` is essentially doing `alert(lien);`

Comment: @sircapsalot -- Yeah those quotes are essentially useless, unless OP is just using them as a placeholder and plans on adding an actual message later.

Comment: FWIW, the equivalent to `$('#show').attr('href')` is `obj.getAttribute('href')`. `obj.href` will return a full URL, not the actual value of the `href` *attribute*. Just pointing out, maybe the OP even wants the complete URL :)

Comment: @FelixKling -- Thanks for that, I'll add it to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple elements with same ID. `$('#show')` will always select the *first* elements with that ID.

Give the elements a class and use jQuery to bind the event handler:

```
<a class="show" href="monlien1"> Facebook</a>
<a class="show" href="monlien2"> Twitter</a>
<a class="show" href="monlien3"> Google</a>
```

and

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Learn about jQuery and event handling: http://learn.jquery.com/events/.